# How to generate accept signal for dialog.exec in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, signals, exit-code, qdialog

In main.py

```
returnCode = self.rouDialogForm.exec_()
if returnCode == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
    print(float(self.rouDialogForm.ui.leStartMhz.text()))

if returnCode ==QtWidgets.QDialog.Rejected:
    print(float(self.rouDialogForm.ui.leStopMhz.text()))
```

In rouDialog.py

```
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    #GUI CODE
    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    self.butConnect.clicked.connect(self.acceptDialog)

def acceptDialog(self):
    self.accept()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        #Label set texts are here
        import myResources_rc
```

I can catch the Rejected signal that is generated after clicking the window closing icon and print out the required text from the line edit.
But when I press the button that will generate accept signal(but connect) program just crashes run time.

I tried different syntax and different imports to make it work.

attempt #1: in rouDialog.py instead of self.accept()

```
self.done(QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted)
```

another attempt: in rouDialog.py instead of self.accept()

```
super(Ui_Dialog,self).accept()
```

another one:

```
QtWidgets.QDialog.accept(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
Adding this to my rouDialog.py solved all my problems.Hope it will help someone else in future.

```
    self.butReadout.clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def accept(self):
        pass
```

Edit: I can't mark my answer as correct , since i need to wait 2 days.